# Are there any special considerations for SEO when using WordPress as PWA and AMP?

Tags: seo, wordpress, amp

I've been tasked with researching the capabilities of combining WP with progressive web apps (PWAs) and accelerated mobile pages (AMP) for the company I work for. I see there are methods of doing this and it all looks very promising. The one big question whether there are any SEO gotchas or considerations we may have to accommodate.

My understanding of this strategy is:

On the mobile side:

We use AMP search engine results to drive people to an AMP landing page. Should be superfast, no?

From the AMP landing page navigation takes the user to the WP PWA. From there IF the user decides to download, we'll have the ability to utilize PWA functionality (eg. notifications)

From the desktop side, the WordPress PWA is delivered as normal thru regular search results

We use Yoast for SEO, btw.

This strategy seems to have the speed benefit for mobile, the interactivity of PWAs (if downloaded) and a largely undisturbed browsing experience otherwise.

It seems a little too perfect, so I'm sure I'm missing something :)

What are the pros, cons, gotchas involved with this especially on the SEO side?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if everything is going perfect you can get benefits with these works.

For now it's important to use Lighthouse:

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/lighthouse/

https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/lighthouse-pwa-analysis-tool

for PWA analysis.